# How do I communicate with the Uno using R through RStudio?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on a real time application which is recording sensor data continuously. I need to process the data in realtime using R. Is there a way to connect and communicate with the uno board through RStudio via serial port?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a serial interface for R; Best bet would be for this to be migrated to SO.

Comment: @MatthewG. Side Note: Migration paths don't exist for private betas.

Comment: Ahh, good point.

Answer (score 1):

If RStudio has serial support. Yes, it can talk to a Uno. If it does not. No.

This is really a question about RStudio (and actually just pure [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29)), not arduinos.

Furthermore, RStudio is just an IDE. Therefore, no, *RStudio* can *not* communicate with an arduino, compile a program, or do much of all aside from edit source-code files. RStudio does not run your code at all. It uses an external interpreter to run your source files.

*R*, on the other hand probably *can* talk to serial interfaces. The fact that you're using RStudio is entirely irrelevant.

I'm not familliar with R, but a little googling leads me to think that R can talk to serial interfaces without *too* much trouble, though I have not been able to find any information about doing so on windows. What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to figure out directly how to read from a serial port using R; While there does seem to have been at least [one attempt](https://biostatmatt.com/archives/112) to provide this, it's not clear that it ever graduated to something supported or easily installable.

Having said that, R does have [`read.socket` and `write.socket`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/read.socket.html), which I believe would make it easy enough to use through [`ser2net`](http://ser2net.sourceforge.net), which exposes a serial-port as a socket.